# The style.css stylesheet doesn’t contain a valid theme header

Tags: themes, css, errors, headers

when I try to upload a theme I have uploaded on a free host and it is the first time I upload a theme on a host, I got this error failed because 
The style.css stylesheet doesn’t contain a valid theme header.

then I put this on my styles.css , but still getting this error , although the theme works very well on the localhost. 
what should I do, please?

```
/*
    Theme Name: shah
    Author: shah
    Author URI: http://shah.gq
    Description: Wordpress Theme
    Version: 1.0
*/
```

Comment: Themes require a style.css file with this header. Your question mentions a styles.css file, plural, which is incorrect.

Comment: thanks for comment, I changed it, but still getting the same error

Comment: Try removing the white space from the beginning of each line. And make sure it’s at the very top.

Comment: changed it , but still getting the same error

Comment: Just try by coping all the theme header from here(https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/) and add the your needed things in header. Some of the hosts check for the params in that header like Theme URI, Author URI etc. May be blocking those things to you.

Comment: There’s something else wrong then, or you’re not uploading the wrong files. There’s not enough information in the question to help any further.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra space from the header. Try like below:

```
/*
Theme Name: shah
Theme URI: 
Author: shah
Author URI: http://shah.gq
Description: Wordpress Theme
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

use same name for theme and also for your  folder

Comment: Please add some further details. Thanks.